# How to get os version of mobile app from GA

Tags: ios, macos, google-analytics

my app is in OSX platform, now i want to get the operating system version for each event. Right now, i can create a custom dimension cd1=xxx to implement this and use dimension to filter it. But if i want to get the same data from the `"reporting->Audience-> Overview -> Operating System"`, all are "not set". So who can tell me is there any way to get os version without creating custom dimension?

```
v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=event&xxxxxx
```

what is the parameter for operating system?

Comment: Why is this tagged iOS if it's for OSX?

Comment: because i think ios also have the same problem, but my application is only in osx